# Speed up creation of thousands of files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I wrote a python application which writes json files to disk.

Creating 15k files takes more than an hour. Can I speed up this process by using multithreading or concurrency in python?

Comment: Sure you can - what have you tried, what specific problems are you having?

Comment: The answer is yes. But what have you tried and what kinda problem you faced?

Comment: Yes, obviously you can. Have you faced any problems?